# I need help!How can i trigger wav files from text file after i give a command?(EXAMPLE GIVEN)

Tags: c#

Commands.txt + Response + wav

Wav location is written in a text file, and to play .wav you give a spoken command, and it reads the location like this Commands = Responses( C:\JARVIS\A.I. Sound Files\droopy_mad.wav )then wav/video plays threw media player

i can get it play threw the script but i can't get it to read from text file to open the wav instead of a string.

```
//Grammar and Responses
string[] grammarFile = (File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\jenas\Desktop\USB backup\Brain\Commands.txt"));
string[] responseFile = (File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\jenas\Desktop\USB backup\Brain\Responses.txt"));

//Speech synth
SpeechSynthesizer speakSynth = new SpeechSynthesizer();

//Speech Rec
Choices grammarList = new Choices();
SpeechRecognitionEngine speechRecognition = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();

SpeechRecognitionEngine _recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();

#region Main talking 

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Intitiaate Grammar
    grammarList.Add(grammarFile);
    Grammar grammer = new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(grammarList));

    try
    {
        speechRecognition.RequestRecognizerUpdate();
        speechRecognition.LoadGrammar(grammer);
        speechRecognition.SpeechRecognized += rec_SpeechRecognized;
        speechRecognition.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
        speechRecognition.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);

        _recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
        _recognizer.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(new Choices(File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\jenas\Desktop\USB backup\Brain\Basic Commands.txt")))));
        _recognizer.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(_recognizer_SpeechRecognized);
        _recognizer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);


    }
    catch
    {
        return;
    }
    speakSynth.SelectVoiceByHints(VoiceGender.Female);

}

public void say(string text)
{
    speakSynth.SpeakAsync(text);
}

private void rec_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{        
    string result = e.Result.Text;
   int resp = Array.IndexOf(grammarFile, result);
    TMRListen.Start();
    //toolStripStatusLabel3.Text = e.Result.Text;
    if (responseFile[resp].IndexOf('+') == 0)
{
       List<string> responses = responseFile[resp].Replace('+', ' ').Split('|').Reverse().ToList();
        Random r = new Random();
  say(responses[r.Next(responses.Count)]);

        //speechRecognition.RecognizeAsyncCancel();


    }
}

private void _recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    bool isValid = false;
    int ranNum = rnd.Next(1, 10);
    string speech = e.Result.Text;
    // label2.Text = e.Result.Text;
    e.Result.Confidence.CompareTo(10);
    toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = e.Result.Text;

    switch (speech)
    {


        //FIRST CASE STATEMENT
        case "Test":

           // TestPhase();

            isValid = true;
            break;

        case "Test two":

           // Greeting();

            isValid = true;
            break;

        //SECOND CASE STATEMENT
        case "Thanks":
            if (isValid)
            {
                speakSynth.Speak("No problem");
            }
            isValid = false;
            break;
    }
}

public void TestPhase()
{

    speakSynth.SpeakAsyncCancelAll();
    // List of files from directory, sorted by *.wav type.
    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\jenas\Desktop\USB backup\Brain\RadioVocals\Defence", "*.wav",SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    // Random number from 0 to the amount of files you have
    Random rnd = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
    int choices = rnd.Next(filePaths.Length);

    // Create a new player with a random filepath from the array
    SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(filePaths[choices]);
    player.Play();
}

public void Greeting()
{
    speakSynth.SpeakAsyncCancelAll();
    // List of files from directory, sorted by *.wav type.
    string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\jenas\Desktop\USB backup\Brain\RadioVocals\Emotions\Greeting", "*.wav", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    // Random number from 0 to the amount of files you have
    Random rnd = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
    int choices = rnd.Next(filePaths.Length);

    // Create a new player with a random filepath from the array
    SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(filePaths[choices]);
    player.Play();
}

private void listenToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{ }

private void TMRListen_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    speakSynth.Speak(" ");
    TMRListen.Stop();        
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void restartToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.Restart();
}

private void menuStrip1_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
{

}

private void teachMeToolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TeachMe School = new TeachMe();
    School.Show();
}
```

When I speak a command, it will come back with a response, and then once the response is finished, a certain .wav location will play from a text file like so.

User Command|Bot Response|Wav location

Comment: Welcome!  In the future, I suggest you not prefix your title with exclamatory demands such as "I need help!" -- it's rather presumptuous.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, ill keep that in mind.